# Chart or diagram for this figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, pstricks

How could I create this table or diagram, I appreciate the help.
[image]

Comment: We, in turn, appreciate the code you have tried so far.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates all you have tried. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Just draw it in `Inkscape` and export to TikZ!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't normally answer a "do-this-for-me" question, but I was bored.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,shapes.callouts,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{caja/.style={minimum height=.5cm, align=center,text depth=0ex, draw},
  encabezado/.style={font=\bfseries, minimum height=0.75cm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[]}]

\matrix [ampersand replacement=\&, column sep=0cm, row sep=0cm, 
  draw, thick, inner sep=1ex] (mesa) 
{
\& 
\node [encabezado, minimum width=4.5cm] (profesor) {PROFESOR}; 
\& 
\node [encabezado, minimum width=4cm] (grupo) {GRUPO}; 
\& 
\node [encabezado, minimum width=4cm] (alumno) {ALUMNO}; 
\\
\node [encabezado, rotate=90] (preparacion) {PREPARACION}; 
\&
\node [caja] (eleccion)    at (0,1) {Elecci\`on del caso};
\node [caja] (formulacion) at (0,0) {Formulaci\`on objectivos};
\node [caja] (formacion)   at (0,-1) {Formaci\`on grupos};
\&
\node [caja] (lectura) at (0,0) {Lectura caso};
\node [caja] (resumen) at (0,-1) {Resumen oral};
\&
\node [rectangle callout, draw, font=\large,
  callout relative pointer=(225:.5)] at (0,-.5) {Fuentes};
\\
\node [encabezado, rotate=90, minimum width=4.5cm] (desarrollo) {DESARROLLO};
\&
\node [caja] (conductor) {Conductor de \\ la actividad};
\&
\node [caja] (estudio grupal) at (0,1.5) {Estudio grupal};
\node [caja] (debate)         at (0,0.6) {Debate};
\node [caja] (elaboracion)    at (0,-1) 
  {Elaboraci\`on y \\ exposici\`on de \\ conclusiones};
\&
\node [caja] (estudio individual) at (0,1.5) {Estudio individual};
\\
\node [encabezado, rotate=90] (evaluacion) {EVALUACI\`ON};
\&
\node [caja] (evaluacion final) 
  {Evaluaci\`on final \\ del proceso y de las \\ aportaciones};
\&
\node [caja] (evaluacion grupo) 
  {Evaluaci\`on de \\ los miembros \\ del grupo};
\&
\node [caja] (autoevaluacion) 
  {Autoevaluaci\`on};
\\};

\draw [->] (eleccion)       -- (formulacion);
\draw [->] (formulacion)    -- (formacion);
\draw [->] (lectura)        -- (resumen);
\draw [->] (resumen)        -- (estudio grupal) coordinate [pos=1/3] (@);
\draw [->] (estudio grupal) -- (debate);
\draw [->] (debate)         -- (elaboracion);
\draw [->] (elaboracion)    -- (evaluacion grupo);
\draw [->] (conductor)      -- (evaluacion final);

\draw [<->] (estudio grupal)   -- (estudio individual);
\draw [<->] (evaluacion grupo) -- (autoevaluacion);
\draw [<->] (conductor.east) -| ($(conductor)!.5!(elaboracion)$) |- (elaboracion.west);

\draw [dashed, ->] (@) -| (estudio individual);
\draw [dashed, ->] (formacion.east) -- (lectura.south west);

\foreach \a in {preparacion, desarrollo, evaluacion}
    \draw [dotted] (\a.north east) --  (\a.north east -| alumno.south east);
\foreach \a in {profesor, grupo, alumno}
    \draw [dotted] (\a.north west) --  (\a.north west |- evaluacion.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]